# Split NumPy array into individual parts with all zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a one-dimensional `np.array` which has the following pattern

1. `array = [seq_1, seq_2, seq_3]`
2. `seq_1` and `seq_3` are all `0`
3. `seq_2` contains at least a single `1`

and I want to split `array` into `seq_1`, `seq_2` and `seq_3`.

For example,

```
array = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
seq_1, seq_2, seq_3 = [0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [0,0,0]
array = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
seq_1, seq_2, seq_3 = [0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0]
array = [0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]
seq_1, seq_2, seq_3 = [0], [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1], [0]
```

Is there a way using only `NumPy` functions (meaning no for loop) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indices to split on using `np.diff` and `np.flatnonzero`:

```
index = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(array)) + 1
```

Then you can split on the index:

```
seq = np.split(array, index)
```

If you want to unpack:

```
seq_1, seq_2, seq_3 = seq
```

As a one-liner:

```
seq_1, seq_2, seq_3 = np.split(array, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(array)) + 1)
```

This method will break up any array into homogeneous sequences, regardless of the values.